# insert a values in a cell by column's name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet shared it with others. My sheet name is "OrderList". I have written the following code,I want to use the column name in this code instead of using the column number. The first row is frozen in this table.

```
var COLUMNTOCHECK1 = 5;
var COLUMNTOCHECK2 = 6;

var DATETIMELOCATION1 = [0, 2];
var DATETIMELOCATION2 = [0, 3];

var SHEETNAME = 'OrderList'

function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME) {
        var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
        if (selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK1) {
            var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
            var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION1[0], 
DATETIMELOCATION1[1]);
            dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
            var dateTimeCell1 = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION2[0], 
DATETIMELOCATION2[1]);
            dateTimeCell1.setValue(email);
        }
        if (selectedCell.getColumn() == COLUMNTOCHECK2) {
            var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION2[0], 
DATETIMELOCATION2[1]);
            dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of the header cell of that column and compare the value to what you are looking for, by using `sheet.getRange(rangeOfHeaderCell).getValue()==='desired column heading')`. Like so:

```
if (sheet.getRange(1, selectedCell.getColumn(), 1, 1).getValue() == 'Hello World') {
    var dateTimeCell = selectedCell.offset(DATETIMELOCATION2[0], DATETIMELOCATION2[1]);
    dateTimeCell.setValue(new Date());
}
```

You could also easily make that into a function:

```
function getColumnHeading(sheet,columnIndex){
  return sheet.getRange(1,columnIndex,1,1).getValue();
}
```

To get a column by header name instead of offset, that is a little more complicated, but I came up with a simple function that iterates through the available columns. Here is everything put all together and refactored a little:

```
var SHEETNAME = 'OrderList';
var EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME = 'Email Stamp';
var TIMESTAMP_COLUMN_NAME = 'Time Stamp';

function onEdit(e) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    if (sheet.getSheetName() == SHEETNAME) {
        // Lookup columns
        var emailColumn = getColumnByHeader(EMAIL_COLUMN_NAME, sheet);
        var timestampColumn = getColumnByHeader(TIMESTAMP_COLUMN_NAME, sheet);
        // Get active cell details
        var selectedCell = ss.getActiveCell();
        var selectedColumnName = getColumnHeading(sheet,selectedCell.getColumn());
        // Set values in corresponding columns
        if (selectedColumnName == 'My Special Column') {
            var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
            if (timestampColumn) {
                sheet.getRange(selectedCell.getRow(), timestampColumn, 1, 1).setValue(new Date());
            }
            if (emailColumn){
                sheet.getRange(selectedCell.getRow(),emailColumn,1,1).setValue(email);
            }
        }
        else if (selectedColumnName == 'Hello World') {
            if (timestampColumn) {
                sheet.getRange(selectedCell.getRow(), timestampColumn, 1, 1).setValue(new Date());
            }
        }
    }
}

function getColumnByHeader(headerName, sheet, rowIndex) {
    rowIndex = typeof (rowIndex) !== 'undefined' ? rowIndex : 1;
    // Get full range of header row
    var headerRange = sheet.getRange(rowIndex, 1, 1, sheet.getDataRange().getLastColumn());
    var headerValues = headerRange.getValues()[0];
    for (var x = 0; x < headerValues.length; x++) {
        if (headerValues[x] == headerName) {
            return x + 1;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function getColumnHeading(sheet, columnIndex) {
    return sheet.getRange(1, columnIndex, 1, 1).getValue();
}
```

Comment: And I want to use the column name instead of "offset" class?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you wanted to do that as well. I've updated my answer with a full script that handles that.

Comment: can you explain "getColumnByHeader" function please?

Comment: It allows you to find a column (and its corresponding index integer) by what should be in it's header (the first cell of the first row). There is no built-in function to do this in Google Sheets, so I wrote that as a quick workaround. It returns false if it can't find it, which allows you to check for a found column and avoid trying to write to a column that does not exist.

Comment: Why, when I run, it sends the message "TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of undefined."?

Comment: I tested the code I provided and it worked without error... Are you trying to use that function (`getColumnByHeader`) outside of the code I provided? If so, note that the second argument is required, and it needs to be a sheet object.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Feel free to mark the answer as "accepted" if there are no further issues with it.